# Are my requirements easily satisfied with PHP alone, or would I benefit from something like a CMS?

Tags: php, authentication, frameworks, content-management-system

I have decided to hone my minimal web back-end experience (and help a friend) by putting in some components for a simple site on shared hosting (1 & 1).

The main functionality for the site is currently to simply store and be able to upload weekly ~20-30 minute audio files, along with some data about them, such as author, date, title, etc.

I would be reasonably comfortable implementing something to handle this using PHP (it's what I have available) and a database to store paths to the files and other info, but I realize that since I require authentication before allowing someone to upload or edit audio files, this would require me to re-implement something which I imagine has been done hundreds of times before.

For a simple application like this, I feel that a fully-fledged CMS would be overkill. Are there existing tools to perform tasks like authentication easily? I'd hate to badly and insecurely reinvent the wheel, but I also don't want to drown in days of documentation just to figure out how to bend e.g. WordPress to my simple application.

What would be a good way to go about this?

Thanks! Any guidance is welcome! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP will probably do what you want, after reading the tutorial you should be able to set up something really quick.

http://cakephp.org/

And on authentication in CakePHP

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication

Cake will also make setting up the user interface to the DB a BREEZE. An incredibly worthwhile tool.

Answer (score 1):

There are frameworks and documentation for specific parts of your application. For example, you could implement authentication using OpenID (just like SO!)

Answer (score 0):

erm....how long is a piece of string?

FWIW, I first installed a copy of dokuwiki for use as a very simple CMS for some static content, then discovered I could easily embed PHP code within it; normally I maintain the PHP file elsewhere and:

```
<php>
include('path/to/some/code.php');
</php>
```

(the php tags are Dokuwiki's tags for marking PHP code). Since then I've used it as a base for some very complex applications.

Compared with other CMS I've worked with, it's a breeze to configure, set up and add your own code to.

And unlike most frameworks it provides authentication, navigation control and tools for managing accounts, along with templating, SEO, version control....